# Error message: The current SKU does not support 'private endpoint connection'

Tags: azure, terraform, azure-app-configuration

I created a private link for app configuration in Azure cloud.

My terraform code:

```
resource "azurerm_virtual_network" "example" {
  name                = "example-network"
  address_space       = ["10.0.0.0/16"]
  location            = var.location
  resource_group_name = var.resource_group_name
}

resource "azurerm_subnet" "service" {
  name                 = "service"
  resource_group_name  = var.resource_group_name
  virtual_network_name = azurerm_virtual_network.example.name
  address_prefixes     = ["10.0.1.0/24"]

  enforce_private_link_service_network_policies = true
  enforce_private_link_endpoint_network_policies = true
}

resource "azurerm_subnet" "endpoint" {
  name                 = "endpoint"
  resource_group_name  = var.resource_group_name
  virtual_network_name = azurerm_virtual_network.example.name
  address_prefixes     = ["10.0.2.0/24"]

  enforce_private_link_endpoint_network_policies = true
}

resource "azurerm_app_configuration" "appconf" {
  name                = "app-butfa"
  resource_group_name = var.resource_group_name
  location            = var.location

}


resource "azurerm_private_endpoint" "example" {
  name                = "butfa-endpoint"
  location            = var.location
  resource_group_name = var.resource_group_name
  subnet_id           = azurerm_subnet.endpoint.id


  private_service_connection {
    name                           = "butfa-privateserviceconnection"
    private_connection_resource_id = azurerm_app_configuration.appconf.id
    is_manual_connection           = false
    subresource_names              = ["configurationStores"]
  }
}
```

But when I run : `terraform apply` I got this error:

```
Error: creating Private Endpoint "butfa-endpoint" (Resource Group "DefaultResourceGroup-SEA"): network.PrivateEndpointsClient#CreateOrUpdate: Failure sending request: StatusCode=0 -- Original Error: Code="SkuFeatureNotSupported" Message="Call to Microsoft.AppConfiguration/configurationStores failed. Error message: The current SKU does not support 'private endpoint connection'." Details=[]

  on init.services.tf line 62, in resource "azurerm_private_endpoint" "example":
  62: resource "azurerm_private_endpoint" "example" {
```

Does anyone help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Default of sku app configuration is `free`

set `sku` to `standard`

```
resource "azurerm_app_configuration" "appconf" {
  name                = "app-butfa"
  resource_group_name = var.resource_group_name
  location            = var.location
  sku                 = "standard"

}
```

Comment: The sku is a required parameter in the more recent API versions of App Configuration. Your terraform may be using an older API version.